# is SASL missing? Franz-go kafka authentication issue

Tags: go, apache-kafka, backend, franz-go

I am getting these error messages

> "re-updating metadata due to err: broker closed the connection immediately after a request was issued, which happens when SASL is required but not provided: is SASL missing?"
> "read from broker errored, killing connection after 0 successful responses (is SASL missing?)"

I am trying to add authentication.
My code for that is:

```
auth := scram.Auth{
        User: "kafka_user",
        Pass: "kafka_pass",
    }
    
    cl, err := kgo.NewClient(
        kgo.SeedBrokers(seeds...),
        kgo.DialTLSConfig(tlsConfig),
        kgo.SASL(auth.AsSha512Mechanism()),
        kgo.ConsumerGroup(consumerGroupId),
        kgo.ConsumeTopics(topics...),
        kgo.WithLogger(kzap.New(logger.GetLogger())),
    )
```

The requirements for the authentication were:

- SSL: false
- security protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
- SASL mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-512
- Username: <>
- Password: <>

I tried everything from the documentation. Even took help of google bard and Bing AI and tried all possible solution, still this issue is persisting.

Comment: Do you have access to broker logs? If so, what is error on a broker side? Could it be that broker does not accept plaintext connections?

Comment: No I do not have access to broker logs @Vladimir

Comment: I wonder what is in tlsConfig? If requirement for connection is "SSL: false" shuuldn't there be no tlsConfig provided? Could you try it w/o DialTLSConfig option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no issue with the package. The code was not getting deployed and hence the issue was not with the code but the deployment.